# Is there anything like a Python JoinableDeque available?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm relatively new to Python and looking for something like Python's [JoinableQueue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue), but that has deque or stack-like behavior.  Specifically, as I'm processing items in the queue *in different processes*, I'd like to be able to add new items to be processed before what's already in the queue (i.e. push onto the stack or add to the front of the deque). Java has [BlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) which does exactly what I want, but I can't really use Java for this project. Any pointers or new ways of thinking about this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to subclass the JoinableQueue. Usually one can implement a Dequeue by using two (Joinable)Queues. Is there something in particular that doesn't let you do this?

Comment: Yes! I tried subclassing JoinableQueue because it uses a deque internally. Unfortunately it ALSO has a QueueFeederThread running internally that immediately drains the internal deque (self._buffer if you're looking at the code) and sends whatever is added to the deque to a Pipe, where the deque behavior is lost.  I may indeed implement my own Deque using two JoinableQueues if it comes to that, but I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `multiprocessing`, queue semantics isn't just something implemented on top of inter-process communication but is inherent to it. Therefore, the simplest solution is probably to build a joinable stack by using a `JoinableQueue` and implementing pushes to the stack by first getting all tasks into a temporary queue, then queueing the new element and filling back the tasks from the temporary queue. Pushing to the stack from different processes would require some locking to maintain the order of the stack.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I was really hoping that I wouldn't need to implement this myself, but so it goes.